# imagemagick -subimage-search how to output result to file

Tags: imagemagick

I am running the following command:

```
compare -metric RMSE -subimage-search screenshot.png icon.png similiarity.png
```

which outputs:

```
0 <0> @617.0
```

because the icon.png is found within the screenshot.png

I want to grab that output and put it in a file, but using:

```
> result.txt
```

doesn't work (the file is empty)

How can I grab that result and put it in a file?

Answer (score 1):

Just found the answer here: http://www.imagemagick.org/discourse-server/viewtopic.php?f=1&t=12618&start=0

The correct way:

`compare -metric RMSE -subimage-search screenshot.png icon.png similiarity.png 2> result.txt`

Answer (score 0):

Compare outputs to stderr. Just redirect 2fd to file

```
compare -metric RMSE -subimage-search screenshot.png icon.png similiarity.png 2> result.txt
```

See [I/O Redirects](http://www.tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/io-redirection.html) article. Using `&>` will redirect both stdout & stderr to your results file.